# Data/matrix manipulation in R

Tags: r, matrix, sequence, sequencing

Dear stackoverflow community,

I think im experienced with R, but last week R proved me wrong.
I think my problem is very easy to solve, but i can't, so im reaching out for you guys!

I got a problem with my some sequencing data, and want it to be in another form of matrix (like an OTU table).
It's a very large dataset so the table listed below is a fraction of it. In total there are 8 barcodes, and like 14 different species.

it is now in the following matrix/structure:

```
  barcode    name         fraction
1 barcode01  Escherichia  0.2
2 barcode01  Bacteria     0.6
3 barcode02  Escherichia  0.2
4 barcode02  Bacteria     0.3
5 barcode03  Escherichia  0.4
6 barcode03  Bacteria     0.1
```

I want it to be in the following structure (like an OTU table):

```
            barcode01 barcode02 barcode03
Escherichia 0.2       0.2       0.4
Bacteria    0.6       0.3       0.1
```

I tried to write the data as vector:

```
asv <- as.vector(test)
matrix(asv, dimnames = list(asv$barcode, asv$name))
```

but I got an error message saying:

```
Error in matrix(asv, dimnames = list(asv$barcode, asv$name)) : 
  length of 'dimnames' [1] not equal to array extent
```

Does anyone have an answer/solution?
Look out hearing from you!

Kind regards,
Marwin

Comment: a matrix and a data.frame are different; principly in that a matrix must be a single data.typ whereas each column of a data.frame can be of a different type. Are you trying to reshape a data.frame to a matrix, or a matrix to a matrix ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want

```r
library(tidyr)
data |>
  pivot_wider(names_from = barcode, values_from = fraction)
#> # A tibble: 2 × 4
#>   name        barcode01 barcode02 barcode03
#>   <chr>           <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
#> 1 Escherichia       0.2       0.2       0.4
#> 2 Bacteria          0.6       0.3       0.1
```

<sup>Created on 2023-11-08 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Maybe you need to coerce your matrix to class data frame in a previous step.

Data:

```
data <- read.table(text = "  barcode    name         fraction
1 barcode01  Escherichia  0.2
2 barcode01  Bacteria     0.6
3 barcode02  Escherichia  0.2
4 barcode02  Bacteria     0.3
5 barcode03  Escherichia  0.4
6 barcode03  Bacteria     0.1", header = TRUE)
```